# Condonation of Delay petition

Tags: common-law, india

How do I write a condonation of delay petition on a land issue to Revenue divisional officer?

Is there any rule that only lawyer should write this condonation of delay petition?

If not please mention the format of the Condonation of delay petition for a Revenue divisional officer on issue related to Land.
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you ask this question at this "lawyersclubindia.com" [forum for Q&A on civil appeals](http://www.lawyersclubindia.com/forum/display.asp?cat_id=5&forum_id=12).  From some quick searches, it looks like India uses procedure that resembles old fashioned common law pleading. You likely need someone familiar with the idiosyncrasies of the Indian writ system to answer these questions.